# Any chance to upgrade 12.04 to 12.04 studio including the kernel

Tags: 12.04

As a newbie I am not sure how much this question holds a value, feel like to experience studio 12.04 but I do not want o disturb the partition of already installed 12.04 desktop version.

I did synaptic update of list of studio's module available but I am not sure how much it covers the real ethnic studio version. Please suggest how to go ahead to feel 12.04 studio without disturbing the current 12.04 desktop version. I am using AMD 64 bit version CPU. 4gb(3.5) RAM.

Hoping to see positive feedback. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily install everything, including the ubuntustudio real time kernel. You will find detailed instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/InstallingUbuntuStudio#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu). In essence, you would do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-video ubuntustudio-graphics linux-lowlatency
```

Deinstalling it later on is likewise not hard.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu, XUbuntu, LUbuntu, KUbuntu, Ubuntu-Studio, EduBuntu... They all use the same kernel and is the same operating system with different systems and desktops on top. These desktops can be installed and used as you please by just selecting them when you log in.

You can simply install Ubuntu Studio from the software center. There's no partitioning or anything like that. You'll get both software from standard Ubuntu and the additions from Ubuntu Studio. In other words; Ubuntu is Ubuntu; you can have both Kubuntu and Xubuntu at the same time as well, for instance.

You do save quite a bit of downloads if you just install it from the software center, since you have much/most of the software installed already.

Comment: Wrong. Ubuntu studio uses a real time kernel.

Comment: @January: Well, technically it's "low latency"... :P
Another downside appears to be that this kernel has not been updated since the initial release (3.2.0-23)...

Comment: @izx: *technically* I would say that it is *soft* real time kernel, "lowlatency" being just a label of a particular implementation (with "preemptive" being another one, and the Molnar patches creating the *hard* real time kernels) :-) (P.S. to confuse matters some more, there is also "low latency *audio*" as a generic term...)

Comment: It's still the same kernel, just configured differently, isn't it? But the point was, of course, that it's the same system. There's no need to reinstall or anything like that.